# How to access footer or header view of specific section in UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I add header and footer view while creating my table.
What I want to do is to change the content of the footer dynamically and programmatically.
Is there a standard way to get the `UIView` for footer?

I know there is a way which is to add a `UIView` property and assign the foot `UIView` while it is created in `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section`
but I would like to know whether there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could tag your custom section footer view when you create it, e.g., in `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`, like this:

```
mySectionFooterView.tag = kMySectionFooterViewTag;
```

`kMySectionFooterViewTag` can be any `NSInteger` you like.

To access `mySectionFooterView` from some other part of your program you can then use:

```
mySectionFooterView = [myTableView viewWithTag:kMySectionFooterViewTag];
```

`myTableView` is the `UITableView` that includes your custom section footer view. You can typically access `myTableView` as `self.tableView`, when using a `UITableViewController`.

Note that there can be performance considerations with this approach, because `viewWithTag:` will search the entire view hierarchy of `myTableView`.